# Свойства объектов

Tags: javascript

```
function func()
{
    this.size = 50;
    this.addheight = Math.sin(Math.PI/4)*(this.size/2);
}

obj1 = new func();
obj3 = new func();
obj3.size = 40;
```

Друзья, подскажите пожалуйста, почему в данном случае в obj3 свойству size присвоилось значение 40, а addheight осталась 50 по умолчанию в obj3, и как нужно правильно объявлять свойства в случае таких сложных выражений. Заранее спасибо

Comment: потому что addHeight считается при создании, а size вы меняете уже после?

Comment: teran, да, именно так. Мне надо size задавать позже, как поступить? Можно и addheight "дозадать" всякий раз, но наверняка с помощью железяки можно умнее сделать))

Comment: магии не будет, либо менять при записи size, либо считать при обращении.

Comment: Так, то есть всякий раз задавать addheight, высчитывать самой? А второй способ?  Попробовала просто объявить this.size; без значения по умолчанию, а задала уже потом. Так вообще пропали все линии, где участвует addheight.

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать магию сеттеров:

```js
class func {
  constructor(){
    this._size = 50;
    this.addheight = Math.sin(Math.PI/4)*(this.size/2);  
  }
  set size(value) {
    this.addheight = Math.sin(Math.PI/4)*(value/2);
    this._size = value;
    return value;
  }
  get size(){
    return this._size;
  }
}

obj = new func();
console.log(obj);
obj.size = 40;
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Darth, огромнейшее спасибо, обязательно изучу тему сеттеров, но сейчас возникли сложности с внедрением. Вот нативный код https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/04pe3362/4/

Comment: Вот вставила set, get, обернула конструктор, https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/04pe3362/5/ все пропало

Comment: @Наташа синтаксис поправил - https://jsfiddle.net/04pe3362/6/

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо

Comment: убедитесь в том, что поддерживается во всех, интересующих вас браузерах (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)